# What's a good way of caching information in an Android App?

Tags: android, caching

If I have a lot of images that I would like to cache, what would be the ideal way?

I was thinking SQLite, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few different ways of persisting data with Android as delineated here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html.  The method that's best for you will depend on why you're caching the images and how you use them.

Comment: This is interesting. Thanks for the link :)

Comment: I do not recommend SQLite blobs to store images. android MediaManager use a column with an URI to file to do similar things.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a lot of images then use external storage else it will slow down the performance of mobile. if you store them in phone memory.